# __init__ method that takes multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I did create a new `datetime.date` like object

```
class WorkDate(datetime.date):
    pass
```

The functionality of this `WorkDate` is(*not important for this question*) that when you add a `timedelta` object it will only move to a weekday date. ie when you add a `timedelta(1)` on a Friday dated `WorkDate` it will return the next Monday dated `WorkDate`.

---

How can I `__init__`  `WorkDate` by any one of these two method to create same result

```
x = WorkDate(2017, 8, 3)
y = WorkDate(datetime.date(2017, 8, 3))
```

---

I did try this but not working for initialization with date object

```
class WorkDate(datetime.date):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 3:
            super(WorkDate, self).__init__(args[0], args[1], args[2])
        elif len(args) == 1:
            self.year = args[0].year
            self.month = args[0].month
            self.day = args[0].day
```

Comment: If the dupe doesn't help you, do let us know how and why.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can't understand why i am not able to initialize with date object in my code. It says *an integer is required* when i try to construct with a date object

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to support any number of arguments, accept `*args` .

Then, in your `__init__`, pass these to the `__init__` of the base class.

```
def __init__(*args):
    super(WorkDate, self).__init__(*args)
```

Here's a version for Python 3, with added support for named (keyword) arguments `**kwargs':

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```